# "Stop" hang on "stopping" state when there are more than one workers in distributed mode

Tags: locust

Observed an issue after clicking "stop" load test from web console of master node. "stop" status change to "stopping" status and hang there without reaching "stopped" state. When there is only 1 worker, it reaches properly to "stopped" state.. I had to restart locust master again to restart load test when it was hung on "stopping" state. Issue repeats when I have more than one worker.

I experienced this issue first when running master and workers on AWS fargate containers .Interestingly, there were no errors logged in master and worker containers after pressing stop button. With just single worker container, Stop status properly move to "stopped" on web console master. Having more than 1 worker cause this issue.

Later I could reproduce this issue on local machine without even docker.

When I run locust master and 2 workers from my local MacBook itself, I am experiencing this issue.
There are no errors thrown after clicking "stop". With 1 worker, it work fine and move to "stopped" status.

How to reproduce in local MacBook

1. Start Locust master from one terminal with below command

locust -f my_locustfile.py --master

2. Start 2 locust workers from another 2 terminals with below command

locust -f my_locustfile.py --worker.

(Ignored "--master-host" parameter here as it is local run. In AWS Fargate setup, we have that parameter)

After this master web console(http://0.0.0.0:8089/) shows 2 workers connected, also load test work fine. When click on "stop" it changes to "stopping" and never come to "stopped".

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not enough information to go off of to help you. Need to know the version of Locust you're using and see some of your code in your locustfile. You could be doing things in your code that make it difficult for Locust to stop, or overloading the worker so it can't receive and process the stop message from the master. Can you reproduce the issue using an example file from the Locust repo on GitHub?

Comment: Thanks .I used this sample locustfile from locust documentation from locust 

`from locust import HttpUser, task

class HelloWorldUser(HttpUser):
   @task
    def hello_world(self):
       self.client.get("/hello")
       self.client.get("/world") `

With having 1 worker , it is working fine. Issue happens only when there is more than one worker.

Answer (score -2):

This appears to be a Bug with the locust tool that was mentioned on github back in 2020, but remains unfixed until now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).